# Centrar textos/"selectores" con HTML y CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Estoy haciendo una página web, y no he encontrado la forma de centrar estos "selectores". Se me van para un lado.

[image: Captura de Ejemplo]

Probé con el típico `<center>` de HTML, pero no tuve resultados. Se ve parecido a mi deseado resultado final, pero igualmente se ve mal, no hay separación entre la "linea1" y la "linea2" de "selectores".

[image: Ejemplo2]

Mi código HTML (la parte que quiero editar) y el código de CSS (COMPLETO) del proyecto de la página web

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

:root {
    --bg-color: #121212;
    --main-color: rgb(255, 81, 0);
    --main-hover-color: rgb(255, 119, 56);
    --second-color: #1a1a1a;
    --third-color: #2c2c2c;
    --nav-text-color: #98999b;
    --nav-text-hover-color: #fffce4;
    --heading-color: #fffce4;
    --small-text-color: #c7c7c7;
    --very-small-text-color: #999999;
}

/* random */

.categorys {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 10px;
}

h1 {
    color: var(--heading-color);
}

h2 {
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    color: var(--heading-color);
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.825rem;
    margin: 1.3rem 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: var(--small-text-color);
}

p {
    color: var(--very-small-text-color);
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: 0.35s;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: var(--main-hover-color);

}

.reveal {
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(150px);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2s ease;
}

.reveal.active {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 100px auto;
    max-width: 1100px;

}

.title {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.th1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.thr {
    width: 180px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.thr hr {
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    height: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

svg {
    display: block;
}

.curve {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    fill: var(--second-color);
}



.curved {
    background-color: var(--second-color);
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    fill: var(--bg-color);
}

/* random end */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);

}



/* navbar */
header {
    height: 80px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 70px;
    background-color: transparent;
}



.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--heading-color);
}

.nav-area {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-area li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-area li a {
    transition: .3s;
    color: var(--nav-text-color);
    font-size: 17px;
}

.nav-area li a:hover {
    color: var(--nav-text-hover-color);
}

.btn-area {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--heading-color);
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: var(--main-color);
    transition: .35s;
}

.btn-area:hover {
    background-color: var(--main-hover-color);
}

::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: #007bff;
}

/* navbar end */

/* home */

.home {
    margin-top: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}



.bot-description {
    margin-right: 150px;
}

.home-btn {
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: none;
    background: var(--main-color);
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .35s;
}

.home-btn:hover {
    background-color: var(--main-hover-color);
}

.home-img img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

/* home end */
/* features */
.features {
    background-color: var(--second-color);
}



.feature h4 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 1rem 0 0.6rem;
}

.features-grid {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.feature {
    background: none;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 2px solid var(--third-color);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.feature:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.feature i {
    font-size: 3.45rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

.feature1 i,
.feature1 h4,
.feature1 .cta {
    color: #42b7ca;
}

.feature1:hover {
    border: 2px solid #42b7ca;
}

.feature2 i,
.feature2 h4,
.feature2 .cta {
    color: #425fca;
}

.feature2:hover {
    border: 2px solid #425fca;
}

.feature3 i,
.feature3 h4,
.feature3 .cta {
    color: #9c42ca;
}

.feature3:hover {
    border: 2px solid #9c42ca;
}

.feature4 i,
.feature4 h4,
.feature4 .cta {
    color: #50ad1a;
}

.feature4:hover {
    border: 2px solid #50ad1a;
}

.feature .cta span {
    font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.feature>* {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.feature .cta {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

/* features end */

/* commands */
.wrapper nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper .categorys {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 720px;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.categorys span {
    padding: 7px 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid var(--main-color);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.categorys span.active,
.categorys span:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: var(--main-color);
}

.commands {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.commands .command {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 7px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: var(--second-color);
}

.commands .command span {
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 98%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: var(--third-color);
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    ;
}


.cmdinfo {
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.cmdinfo p {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    color: var(--small-text-color);
}

.cmdali {
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: -2.75%;
    color: var(--very-small-text-color);
}

.cmdali p {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.commands .command.hide {
    display: none;
}

.commands .command.show {
    animation: animate 0.4s ease;
}

/* commands end */


/* faq */
.faq {
    background-color: var(--second-color);
}

main#questions {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.live-search-box {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0px;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid var(--bg-color) !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.live-search-box:focus {
    border: 1px solid !important;
}

.topic {
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background: var(--bg-color);
    margin: 5px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.topic h2.question {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.open {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
}

.open:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.expanded {
    background-color: var(--third-color);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.ptag {
    display: none;
}

.question {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--small-text-color);
}

.answer {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.faq-t {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    border-left: 2px solid var(--main-color);
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--main-color);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.faq-o {
    top: -50px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-224deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-224deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-224deg);
    transform: rotate(-224deg);
}

.live-search-box {
    background: var(--bg-color);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0px;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid var(--third-color) !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: var(--very-small-text-color);
}

/* faq end */
/* footer */
footer {
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: var(--second-color);
    align-items: center;
}



.foot {
    flex-direction: column;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 250px;
    color: white;
}

/* footer end */
/* @ */
@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}



@media (max-width: 1200px) {

    .wrapper nav .categorys {
        max-width: 600px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        max-width: 695px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    nav .categorys span {
        padding: 7px 15px;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width:900px) {
    .features-grid {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 710px) {
    .wrapper nav .categorys {
        max-width: 600px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        max-width: 450px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    nav .categorys span {
        padding: 7px 15px;
    }

    header {
        padding: 10px 25px;
    }

    .top-nav {
        display: none;
    }

    .home {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .home-text {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .bot-description {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .nav-area li a {
        font-size: 12.25px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wrapper {
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    .wrapper nav .categorys {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    nav .categorys span {
        margin: 5px;
    }
}

/* @ end */
```

```html
        <nav>
            <div class=" categorys">
                <span class="category active" data-name="all">Todos</span>
                <span class="category" data-name="apis">APIS/CHECKS</span>
                <span class="category" data-name="perfil">Perfil</span>
                <span class="category" data-name="util">Utilidad</span>
                <span class="category" data-name="roleplay">Roleplay</span>
                <span class="category" data-name="economia">Economía</span>
                <span class="category" data-name="interaccion">Interacción</span>             
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Si cargas el código CSS será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Editado. Agregué los archivos del sitio.

Comment: No pongas enlaces externos para mostrar tu código. Las preguntas debes ser autocontenidas para ser útiles a los demás. Los enlaces externos tienden a desaparecer y la pregunta pierde el sentido. Léete [ask] y [example] para aprender a realizar buenas preguntas para obtener mejores respuestas.

Comment: ¿Cómo se supone que ponga mi código completo dentro de la pregunta?

Comment: No hace falta que pongas tu código completo, claro, solo el extracto del mismo que esté causando ese comportamiento que describes en tu pregunta.  Si te lees el enlace que te he pasado antes: [example] allí lo explica bien.  Piensa que quizás para ti suponga un trabajo extra, pero ponte en nuestro lugar y si debemos analizar **todo** tu código para encontrar el fallo nos estas pasando el trabajo a nosotros y lo más probable es que no nos apetezca esforzarnos si tu tampoco lo haces. Además, también es probable que haciéndolo tu encuentres el fallo antes y acabes borrando la pregunta.

Comment: Así como esta tu código aquí, funciona muy bien y correctamente. Ya solucionaste? Debe ser otro framework u otro link de CSS que sea el problema. Yo probe en Chome y Firefox y todo esta bien...

Comment: Acabo de poner tu código en un snippet en la pregunta, que si lo ejecutas verás que tu problema no se reproduce.  Quizás deberias editar de nuevo la pregunta y el snippet y poner los elementos de HTML que engloban a `<nav>`  para poderlo reproducir correctamente y buscarte la solución.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes centrar los elementos con `display: flex`:

```
.categorys {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y sigue igual, acá te dejo todo el código de la página por si quieres ver si hice algo mal https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bUHL6wJ2mPTohG3ZNCIapn-xP2DY2spm